# How can I stop Macbook Pro from decreasing screen brightness, everytime I remove the MagSafe charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen, power, magsafe

How can I stop the screen dimming on macOS Ventura, everytime I unplug the MagSafe Charger on my 2021 MacBook Pro?

Is there any way to disable this weird energy saving feature. I want my screen to stay 100% no matter what is the charging status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In macOS Ventura settings, you have to go to Displays, then click on Advanced..., then toggle off "Slightly dim the display on battery".

However, the display still gets dimmed if you have Low Power Mode enabled, so make sure it's disabled in the Battery settings.

Comment: Can confirm, this is it. I turned off that pesky "Low Power Mode"' now, unless I'll be traveling. Can confirm also that hijacks the "Slightly dim the display on battery" when turned on

Answer (score 1):

On Ventura, it's System Settings -> Displays -> Advanced -> Slightly dim the display on battery.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a setting for that in the system preferences. Under "screens" -> then "advanced" in the bottom right. There is a setting at the bottom that states something like "dimm brightness slightly when using battery". That should do the trick. I don't know the exact text because I am not English myself but I hope this helps out!